# Jest expect mongoose timestamps

Tags: javascript, mongoose, jestjs

I'm unit testing an Express / Mongoose API using Jest.
However, I'm facing issues concerning expect "_id" and timestamps fields ("createdAt" and "updatedAt" for instance).

```
  const validBody = {
    email: faker.internet.email(),
    lastName: faker.name.lastName(),
    firstName: faker.name.firstName(),
    password: faker.internet.password()
  }

 // creation of an user by API call
 // ...

  const user = await User.findById(response.body.data._id)

  // OK
  expect(user._id).toEqual(expect.anything())
  expect(user.createdAt).toEqual(expect.anything())

  // FAIL
  expect(user).toEqual({
    ...validBody,
    _id: expect.anything(),
    createdAt: expect.anything()
  )}
```

Both first expects match fine. However, the last one using the full object doesn't match, whatever I put in expect.any(...) (even anything()). For instance for createdAt, I've tried "Object, Date, mongoose.Schema.Types.Date, String" ...

Do you have any idea ? I believe mongoose is casting _id and createdAt objects into a plain field during two first expects. But, using expect.anything() in the object should match ... anything ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 4):

I got it working by calling `.toJSON()` in the mongoose instance being tested.

```
// Example

expect(user.toJSON()).toEqual({
    ...validBody,
    _id: expect.anything(),
    createdAt: expect.anything()
)}
```